# the figure is not placed in the correct position, LATEX with figure float position

Tags: latex, figure, pdflatex, floating

the figure is not placed in the correct position, I would like it to continue with the text instead it is positioned at the beginning of the page.
I tried putting `[H]` but it doesn't work

[image]

This is the code from jpp::

```
\newcounter{figure}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tp}
\def\ftype@figure{2}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure}

\newenvironment{figure}{\@float{figure}\fstyle@figure}{\end@float}


\def\fstyle@figure{\normalfont\small\rmfamily}
\def\fjust@figure{\centering}
\def\fcapjust@figure{\centering}
\def\fcapsize@figure{\normalfont\small\scshape}
\def\fcapstyle@figure{\normalfont\small\rmfamily}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question. Depending on the class, it maybe does not have a floating mechanism.

Comment: Your image is huge! If latex doesn't find enough space for a _float_, it waits for next available place, most likely the next page, and fill remaining space with text that is after the image in your code. This is exactly the expected behaviour! You would have to put the float between earlier paragraphs. `[H]` is useless here; even worse it might leave a huge gap between text and end of the page. I recommend to read [this post on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) or its PDF version.